# A combination lock that flashes red, green, or orange

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Say you have a combination lock that takes in a key code in the form of 10 integers from 0 to 9 (in the right order). If you have 0-3 of the integers right, a red light will flash. If you get 4-6 of the integers right, an orange light will flash. And if you get 7-9 of the integers right, a green light will flash and if you get all integers right the lock will open.

It costs $1 per try. What amount of money needs to be in the safe before you will try to open it (What is the expected value of opening this safe?) What is the maximum it will cost us to open this safe?

Comment: Just to check - you have a sequence of ten different numbers - you couldn't have the code $1111111111$? And would it be possible to enter sat $1122334455$ as a test sequence, or would this be rejected?

Comment: I suspect there are many different strategies possible, and the expected value strongly depends on the algorithm you choose to follow. Maybe there is an obvious better method, though. Also, the maximum cost happens when you try every combinations, and that is $10^{10}$, which is a lot of money.

Comment: @MarkBennet No, you can have repeats in the right combination.

Comment: What does getting $k$ integers "right" mean? Does it mean that we have $k$ positions that contain the correct digit, or that $k$ of the digits we entered appear somewhere in the correct cdoe?

Comment: @zuggg do you have to try all $10^{10}$ cases in the worst case though?

Comment: @blf It means $k$ integers in the correct positions or $k$ positions with the correct integer.

Comment: @narcissa Well, then I guess it once again depends on your algorithm!

Comment: The question is a bit unclear. It appears to want the algorithm with the lowest average cost, and then to identify the maximum cost of applying that algorithm. It is possible that there would be an algorithm with a higher average cost, but a lower maximum.

Comment: I am interested in where this problem came from.

Comment: Good point. I'm interested in both.

Comment: This problem came from a Jane Street interview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple algorithm for the upper bound of $10042$:

Start with $0^{10}$ and go to $0^69^4$, there will be at least one orange flash, let say at combination $0^6abcd$. Now try $0^51(a+1)bcd$ to $0^59(a+1)bcd$ to get another orange flash, and continue in similar fashion until you will find all the numbers. The worst-case cost is $10000+6*9$ and the expected is roughly half of that. There are some special cases, e.g. there are some zeros, but it is easy to distinguish from them, e.g. you will get more than one orange flash, that is at least 10 orange flashes and that suffices to check which numbers are zeros.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: Thanks! That's great! $:)$

Comment: @narcissa Be aware that there may be algorithms that have lower expected cost.